# WebSphere ssl configuration for secure ( ssl ) communication with LDAP

Tags: ssl, ldap, websphere

We have Web Service deployed on WebSphere 8.5 that needs to communicate with LDAP over ssl. The ssl communication works only when the ldap certificates are imported in JRE cacerts store.

For other services we use, the certificate can be imported in CellDefaultTrustStore from the console, however the LDAP communication does not work by simply importing the certs on console in CellDefaultTrustStore.

Is there a specific configuration required to avoid using cacerts ? Appreciate any help in this regard.

Here is the code snippet making LDAP connection [ variable names updated ]

```
   Hashtable env = new Hashtable();

   env.put(DirContext.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");
   env.put(DirContext.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
   env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, bindUserName);
   env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, bindPassword);
   // this is the url with ldaps://hostname
   env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, url);

   DirContext dirContext = new InitialDirContext(env);
```

---

Comment: By LDAP, you mean registry configuration in server security settings, or you are doing your own connections to LDAP from the application code?

Comment: Right, this is not related to registry. Our application is connecting to a separate ldap as part of the Web Service business logic.

Comment: Add piece of your code that is making ssl connection, as maybe you are manually overriding some ssl properties.

Comment: Added the code snippet ... variable names modified

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I do not know the details about how your LDAP connection is being made.  If it's going to the cacerts file, it suggests the JSSE default SSL Configuration is being used.  So something about the call is making it go to the JSSE default and not use the WebSphere socket factories.

Comment: Correct, we are basically looking at a way to change from default JSSE to WebSphere socket factory. We tried adding LDAP protocol to the dynamic outbound endpoints , but still it follows the cacerts only. We have another application using the LDAP JNDI API in similar fashion and interestingly it uses the CellDefaultTrustStore. So not sure what really controls this behavior.

Comment: The protocol setting on the dynamic outbound filters is really is for server admin originated things.  If your filter is changed to include just a hostname or a hostname and port does it work?   Can you let me know what is being used to access LDAP.   Like you mention above I have seen JNDI work okay with the WebSphere socket factories.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to leverage dynamic outbound SSL configurations.

1. Configure a trust store when your LDAP's cert.
   (You probably have this already).
2. Create an SSL Configuration for communicating with LDAP
   using trust store from step 1.
3. Create a dynamic outbound endpoint configuration using
   the host/port info of your LDAP.  Reference the SSL
   configuration from step 2.